# Eloquent - Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using `Laravel 5.5` and I am having the following query:

```
                $instru = Instruments::where('name', '=', $coinArr[$key])->first(); 
                $i = Revision::where('id', '=', $instru->revisions_id)->first();
                if ($i ===  NULL) { ...
```

In the setup case `$instru = NULL` hence the query on the `Revision` model does not work.

My problem is that I if I `var_dump($i)` I get the following error and do not run into the `if-clause`.

```
[2017-12-26 21:38:10] local.ERROR: Trying to get property of non-object
```

Any suggestions how to deal with this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change:

```
$i = Revision::where('id', '=', $instru->revisions_id)->first();
```

into:

```
$i = $instru ? Revision::where('id', '=', $instru->revisions_id)->first() : null;
```

This is because in some cases `$instru` is null and you cannot run `$instru->revisions_id` when `$instru` is null